# How to check boundary of a sprite when another sprite is moving? (Cocos2D)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to detect the boundary of a sprite when another sprite is moving to prevent the same position of sprites. How to do it? Any help....

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule method to check position  in init method

```
[self schedule:@selector(update:)];
```

and then

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(sprite1.boundingBox, sprite2.boundingBox)) {
     //do what ever you want    
    }
}
```

Comment: I declare 10 sprites. When they are moving they get into another which I am not expecting. How to move them without get into another. Please show in some code..

Comment: You add all your sprite in an array, loop for all sprites , if the  Intersects each other then move them in other direction... i dont have working code, but its the logic you can implement..